# react-native/android: screen content becomes transparent on navigation

Tags: android, react-native

I have this issue where when I navigate to a new screen, the contents of my first screen(more like parts of it) go semi transparent.

**So this is the initial screen:**

[image]

**When the navigation happens i see something like this:**

[image]

It is not very obvious but you can see a green shadow covering the first screen on navigation. It was white before but changed when i changed the background color of the theme that my main activity uses.

I don't mind the shadow/tint as much as the weird transparency. On some other screens its even worse (can post more screenshots if needed).

I use `StackNavigator` of `react-native-navigation` if that's of any interest.
I have done an app before and never seen this behavior although I did observe that in my other app, when navigating, the screen seems to swipe along the full width of the screens, compared to this new app, where new pages seem to glide on top the previous one.

**UPDATE**: One of my apps that does not have this issue does not use this navigator. It used the **old** navigator provided by `react-native`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* what you would need to change is your `cardStyle` for your `StackNavigator`. You might need to fiddle with some settings for your transition configuration and your CardStyle to achieve what you want.

I don't have a project to test on at the moment, but here is where you would want to change it when you define your stack:

```
const MainStack = StackNavigator(
{
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
    ...
},
{
    stateName: 'MainStack',
    initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
    cardStyle: {
        shadowOpacity: 0,    <------- DEFINE YOUR CARD STYLES HERE
    },
}
);
```

[Here's a link to the relevant code](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/701337024e1c0172af49a030cd0233ee3c3f9dfe/src/views/CardStack/CardStack.js#L433-L453) in the CardStack source code, as you can see it is first getting styles from the current transition config (Lines 434-436) and then the `cardStyle` prop (Line 446)

Let me know if you need some help sorting out what styles exactly to pass in, I can set up a test project to help. **I'd look at setting `opacity: 1` to see if that would achieve what you are looking for.**

Comment: Seems opacity has something to do with my issue. I set cardStyle to {opacity : 1}. The weird shadow vanished. Thanks